# PHP mail: normal characters from link are being replaced

Tags: php, encoding

Im using a simple script to send a test email:

```
 $sql = "SELECT name, update_url FROM `accounts` WHERE `subscription_id` = '4692'";
 $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

 $name = $row["name"];
 $updateUrl = $row["update_url"];

 echo $updateUrl;

 $subject = 'Subscription Payment Has Failed';
 $message = 'Hi ' . $name . ',

 Your subscription payment has failed. You can use the link below to update your payment information if needed:
' . $updateUrl .'

Cheers,
test name';
        $headers = 'From: test ' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"; format=flowed \r\n";
        $headers .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable \r\n";

        mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The problem that I encounter is that,
$updateUrl even though it is stored correctly in the DB, gets sent broken via mail.

To be more exact:
In the DB it is stored like this:
https://test.testsite.com/sub/update?user=406530&subscription=4692&hash=01d75f25e599e3c842ea5288f47e

And in the sent mail it is received like this:
https://test.testsite.com/sub/update?user@6530&subscriptionF92&hash d75f25e599e3c842ea5288f47e

Notice that '=40' is replaced by '@', '=46' by 'F' and '=01' by a blank space.

What could cause this, what sort of representation/encoding of characters is this?

Worth mentioning this still happens when sent as HTML with content-type text/html

Comment: Depending on your email provider, the email is very likely to be sanitized before reaching your inbox in order to protect their users from malicious emails.

Comment: Are you sure you're sending UTF-8? Is your database storing UTF-8?

Comment: You're getting some kind of ASCII hex-code replacement: ASCII hex 40 = `@` ACII hex 46 = `F` while ASCII hex 1 is unprintable so you're getting a space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [RFC2045 quoted-printable encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7) and is entirely normal. The problem is that you're declaring a content-transfer-encoding, but not encoding the content to match, so anything that looks like QP-encoding is getting decoded incorrectly. You need to apply it to the entire MIME part (which in your case is the whole message), not just the URL, using [`quoted_printable_encode`](http://php.net/quoted_printable_encode) like this:

```
mail($email, $subject, quoted_printable_encode($message), $headers);
```

Calling this will also wrap your text to 76 character lines, but that will not affect the appearance of the delivered message as the encoding is lossless.

And please don't tag your questions as PHPMailer if you're not using PHPMailer.

Comment: Yes, that worked. P.s. I removed the wrong tag, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

You must use [quoted_printable_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-encode.php):

[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php) is using this code to encode each line of the message (if it is using the 'quoted-printable' encoding:

```
public function encodeQP($string, $line_max = 76)
{
    // Use native function if it's available (>= PHP5.3)
    if (function_exists('quoted_printable_encode')) {
        return quoted_printable_encode($string);
    }
    // Fall back to a pure PHP implementation
    $string = str_replace(
        array('%20', '%0D%0A.', '%0D%0A', '%'),
        array(' ', "\r\n=2E", "\r\n", '='),
        rawurlencode($string)
    );
    return preg_replace('/[^\r\n]{' . ($line_max - 3) . '}[^=\r\n]{2}/', "$0=\r\n", $string);
}
```

You need to do that to the message you are sending.
At the very least.

Check out the code that PHPMailer is using. Sending emails is a black art.

Comment: That's the wrong way to use quoted-printable encoding. You need to apply it to the entire MIME part, not just parts of it.